# Project Euler #5 JavaScript - solution works with a big mistake in my code

Tags: javascript

I'm still very new with JS and I made my code work even though it's utterly wrong - so I'd appreciate some help!

I was working on the solution for the Problem 5: https://projecteuler.net/problem=5

My thinking was to start with a while loop which executes until it encounters the smallest number that meets the task's criteria.

But when I "finished", I realised the code works even though I didn't reassign the while loop condition to false in my code. It just stops looping on its own and the code doesn't work when the while loop is removed.

I've found some other solutions for this problem, e.g using less common multiple, but I'd prefer to correct my code first.

```
function smallestMultiple(max) {
  var n = max;
  var counter = 0;
  var evenlyDivided = true;

  while (evenlyDivided) {
    for (var i=1; i<=max; i++) {
      if(n%i===0) {
      counter += 1;
        if(counter===max) {
          return n;
        }
      }
      else {
        counter=0;
        n++;
      }
    }
  }
}
smallestMultiple(10);
```

P.S. As I am learning and don't have any JS code good habits developed, all feedback and criticism for my code is more than welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you do a `return` when counter is equal to max. Return means something like end of function, stop right here & return this value! So, when your condition matches, the function - and your while loop - will stop executing.

So, instead of returning a value in the loop, you could set `evenlyDivided` to false there, and return `n` after the while loop.